# Methods for visualising aromaticity

Tags: software, electronic-structure, molecular-modeling

I was wondering what tools there are for visualising aromaticity and anti-aromaticity in molecules, to what quantum chemistry programs they are interfaced, and what other relevant features they have.

So far, I found:

- [ACID](https://www.otto-diels-institut.de/herges/pages_en/projects_acid.html), which is interfaced only to Gaussian. This seems to be a very popular tool but has a rather rigid workflow.
- [GIMIC](https://gimic.readthedocs.io/) interfaced to a number of different programs. This seems to be more flexible but also a bit harder to use.

Answer (score 13):

## Multiwfn

The software [Multiwfn](http://sobereva.com/multiwfn/) can calculated four aromaticity indices, namely FLU, FLU-pi, PDI and information-theoretic index.

*Multiwfn can perform wavefunction analyses based on outputted file of almost all well-known quantum chemistry programs, such as Gaussian, ORCA, GAMESS-US, Molpro, NWChem, Dalton, xtb, PSI4, Molcas, Q-Chem, MRCC, deMon2k, Firefly, CFour, Turbomole* [[1](http://sobereva.com/multiwfn/)]

Answer (score 6):

### Visualsation of chemical shielding tensors

We just developed a new method that might be used as an alternative. It is denoted visualisation of chemical shielding tensors (VIST). The preprint is [available here](https://dx.doi.org/10.26434/chemrxiv.13580885). The idea is that we compute the eigenvectors of the chemical shielding tensor at different points in space and visualise them as little dumb-bells. This representation shows local variations and anisotropy in the shielding, which provides information about local aromaticity.

The method will be released within [TheoDORE](https://theodore-qc.sourceforge.io/). So far, only Gaussian is interfaced but we will certainly add different programs.

[image: Visualisation of chemical shielding tensors]